# NMR: find T1 from signal obtained by two different TR and same TE

Tags: mathematical-physics

The NMR signal can be calculated from the equation
$$S = KH ({1 -e^{-TR/T1}}) {e^{-TE/T2}}   $$
[Reference](http://www.ajronline.org/doi/abs/10.2214/ajr.144.6.1157)
If we alter the TR of a sequence and keep the T2, let the resultant signals be
$$S1 = KH ({1 -e^{-TR1/T1}}) {e^{-TE/T2}}   $$ and 
$$S2 = KH ({1 -e^{-TR2/T1}}) {e^{-TE/T2}}   $$

So,
$$ S1/S2 = \frac{1 -e^{-TR1/T1}} {1-e^{-TR2/T1}}   $$

S1, S2, TR1 and TR2 are known. 
Is there any way find T1 from this ?

Answer (score 0):

writing your equation in the form
$$\frac{S_1}{S_2}=\frac{1-\left(e^{-TR_1}\right)^{1/T_1}}{1-\left(e^{-TR_2}\right)^{1/T_1}}$$
you will get an equation of the form
$$\frac{S_1}{S_2}=\frac{1-a^{1/T_1}}{1-b^{1/T_1}}$$ you can only use a numerical method, if $$a=b$$ you will get a symbolic solution

Comment: If a=b, then TR1 = TR2. Then there wont be any difference between the two equations.